# Understand the proof of the Nakano identity

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry

I was reading Huybrechts complex geometry book, there is a Lemma about Nakano identity in section 5.2.3 as follows:

> **Lemma 5.2.3** (Nakano identity) Let $\nabla$ be the Chern connection on
> $E$. Then $$ \left[\Lambda,
>  \bar{\partial}_E\right]=-i\left(\nabla^{1,0}\right)^*=i\left(\bar{*}_{E^*}
>  \circ \nabla_{E^*}^{1,0} \circ \bar{*}_E\right) . $$

**Proof.**

**Step 1.** (Prove the difference of the operator on both hand side is a linear operator.)

The second equality is the definition of the adjoint operator of $\nabla^{1,0}$.
The first equality is local and we may, therefore, use an orthonormal trivialization $\psi:\left.E\right|_U \cong U \times \mathbb{C}^r$. With respect to such a trivialization the Hodge operator $\bar{*}_E$ becomes the complex conjugate $\bar{*}$ of the usual Hodge operator *. Writing the connection on $E$ with respect to $\psi$ as $\nabla_E=d+A$ one has $\nabla_{E^*}=d+A^*=d-A, \bar{\partial}_E=\bar{\partial}+A^{0,1}$, and $\left(\nabla_E^{1,0}\right)^*=-\bar{*} \circ\left(\partial-A^{1,0}\right) \circ \bar{*}=$ $-* \circ \bar{\partial} \circ *-\bar{*} \circ A^{1,0} \circ \bar{*}=\partial^*-\left(A^{1,0}\right)^*$.
This yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\left[\Lambda, \bar{\partial}_E\right]+i\left(\nabla_E^{1,0}\right)^* } &=[\Lambda, \bar{\partial}]+i \partial^*+\left[\Lambda, A^{0,1}\right]-i\left(A^{1,0}\right)^* \\
&=\left[\Lambda, A^{0,1}\right]-i\left(A^{1,0}\right)^*,
\end{aligned}
$$
where we used the original Kähler identity (Proposition 3.1.12). Thus, the global operator $\left[\Lambda, \bar{\partial}_E\right]+i\left(\nabla_E^{1,0}\right)^*$ turns out to be ($\mathcal{A}^0(X)$-) linear(or in another words bundle homomorphism).

**Step2.** (Prove this linear operator vanishes by checking at each point under a suitable orthonormal trivialization)

In order to show that it vanishes, it thus suffices to choose the orthonormal trivialization $\psi$ in a neighborhood of $x \in X$ such that $A(x)=0$. This can always be achieved.

---

**I can't figure out step 2, why linearity is needed, and why it can vanish after that?**

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If I understand correctly, step $1$ is necessary because it guarantees that the difference of the two operators is a tensor. To show that a tensor vanishes it is sufficient to do so *at each single point* by working in "special" coordinates around the point, which is what is done in step 2. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you @Johnny Lemmon  ,why if the operator is not tensorial then we can not check pointwise?

Comment: Because to check the identity pointwise you fix a local frame around the point a frame with special property. If the operator is zero, it should vanish in every possibile local frame, and if it tensorial it is sufficient to check that it vanishes in one frame. But otherwise it might be that it vanishes in one frame and not in another.

Comment: Hi ,@Johnny Lemmon  . I have a silly question , you know the connection matrix $A$ is also tensorial, and $A(p) = 0$ under the local frame. Does this implies that $A$ is zero operator?

Comment: The connection is *not* tensorial.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin .But for the trivial bundle $A$ in $A+d= D$ is tensorial ?And $A$ can be set under chosen frame to be zero at each point? Does this means $A$ is zero operator? I don't know where goes wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: Triviality of the bundle is irrelevant. I think of it in terms of the classical moving frames set-up: If $A$ is the connection form in one frame and we change frame by $g$ (as a function on our trivializing open set), then $\tilde A = g^{-1}Ag + g^{-1}dg$. The first term is tensorial, but the second messes it up. But using this you can easily see that you can choose $g$ to make $\tilde A(p) = 0$ for any particular $p$. [I personally use the action on the other side, so I have $\tilde A = gAg^{-1} + dg\,g^{-1}$, but it makes no difference.]

Comment: Hi @Ted Shifrin , but you know the difference between two connection should be tensorial and $D$ and $d$ are both connection, therefore $A = D- d$ should be tensorial ? where goes wrong?

Comment: No, I believe you're misinterpreting. We are working in a trivialization, but the bundle $E$ is itself not trivial. So $d$ is not a connection on $E$, although it is on a trivial bundle. Maybe review the discussion on p. 174 of Huybrechts?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin , Consider the case of trivial bundle, then $A$ is tensorial and can be set to zero at each point correct? Does this implies $A$ is zero operator on the trivial bundle?

Comment: I can certainly define connections other than $d$ on the trivial bundle.

Comment: Emm, where goes wrong ? If it's tensorial and pointwise zero, which is not zero operator?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez , but $A$ is tensor on the trivial bundle, it should be zero then ?

Comment: On the trivial bundle $A = D -d$ is tensor and we have proved $A(p) = 0$ so it's pointwise zero? As tensor which is pointwise zero should be zero operator? @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez

Comment: Hi @Ted Shifrin  , I can't figure out, can you help me? You already admit the fact (1) that $A$ is tensorial on trivial bundle (2) under the change of frame it's pointwise zero.  but why it's not zero operator? where goes wrong?